# how to get output from part-r-0000 in apache pig

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-pig, snort

I am parsing pcap file using pig. I am getting output in part-r-0000 file.
It is showing me following output.

```
1101
1646
503
679
556
480
80
471
```

How to get actual output from that file? What is the use of part-r-0000 file?

Comment: What do you mean 'actual' output? `part-r-00000` is, as you say, the output file. Do you mean something else, like the prints that you do in your code, perhaps?

Comment: The code I was executing should show the source, destination, timestamps etc values. But instead of that it is showing above output.

Comment: Then, the problem is the code. Could you add it in the question, please?

Comment: I am using 'packetpig' repo of github. As per code given on [Horton works](http://hortonworks.com/blog/big-data-security-part-two-introduction-to-packetpig/) I was executing `./pigrun.py -x local -r data/web.pcap -f pig/examples/binning.pig` through command line. Since I am beginner, I don't know how to generate output in human readable format. For code please visit [packetpig](https://github.com/packetloop/packetpig/blob/master/pig/examples/binning.pig)

Answer (score 0):

That file is just the output file being stored on HDFS.  If you want the output to go elsewhere you can redirect the output using ">"

Answer (score 0):

You can get the output in pig using Store/Dump.
part-r file is an output file from the reducer.